# count set that it use it in where clause and have condition on it in mdx

Tags: count, where-clause, mdx

I'm new in mdx, i have question about count function and where clause.
if we want count a set that we have condition on it in where clause, condition act on count?
foe rexample:

with
member countofrows as
count([Date].[Date].[Date])

select countofrows on 0
from [Adventure Works]
where ([Date].[Date].&[20050101])

the mention queries must return 1 but the where cluse dont work and it returens 2191 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try the existing keyword:

```
Count(existing [Date].[Date].[Date].Members)
```

Comment: can you explain existing what to do exactly?
I have studied mention link, bud i don't undestand.!!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/mdx-query-existing-keyword

Comment: It forces to check if set members really exist.